# How do i remove rounded tabs in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: java, eclipse

How do i remove rounded corners in Eclipse in order to have this look?
[image]

I tried to change themes in *settings>appearance>themes* from Windows one, to classic.
It didn't work out.
I'm on Windows 10 by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to do. You probably installing the latest eclipse version, but try to install the previous one.
In a "New" eclipse installer, click advanced setting and choose the version eclipse with, "Java 1.6..." in the description, instead of 1.7 or something.
I had the exact same problem, but it fixed that.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can see only the 'Windows XP Blue' and 'Windows XP Olive' themes have the squared tabs.

You can try editing other theme's CSS files which are in the `org.eclipse.ui.themes` plugin. You need to change the `swt-simple` value to `true`:

```css
.MPartStack {
    swt-simple: true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Jeeeyul's Eclipse Themes](https://github.com/jeeeyul/eclipse-themes). You can do that and much more with this.